# how to convert string of unicodes to the char?

Tags: c#, windows, silverlight, windows-phone-7

i have a text file in which sets of Unicodes are written as

"'\u0641'","'\u064A','\u0649','\u0642','\u0625','\u0644','\u0627','\u0647','\u0631','\u062A','\u0643','\u0645','\u0639','\u0648','\u0623','\u0646','\u0636','\u0635','\u0633','\u0641','\u062D','\u0628','\u0650','\u064E','\u062C','\u0626"
"'\u0622'","'\u062E','\u0644','\u064A','\u0645".

I opened the file and started reading of file by using readline method.  I got the above line shown as a line now i want to convert all Unicode to char so that i could get a readable string. i tried some logic but that doesn't worked i stuck with converting string "'\u00641'" to char.

Comment: Where are you getting this file from? It may be simpler to change what's creating it than to parse it.

Comment: we are using these files in our project. i m not getting what u want to say

Comment: But where do the files come from? What's created them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract strings containing individual numbers (using Regex for example), apply Int16.Parse to each and then convert it to a char.

```
string num = "0641"; // replace it with extracting logic of your preference
char c = (char)Int16.Parse(num, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber);
```

Comment: A **char** can be implicitly converted to ushort, int, uint, long, ulong, float, double, or decimal. (From MSDN) You can write: ushort code = c; and variable *code* will hold an unicode value of c.

Comment: If you want to encode it to a string similar to your input file, you should write: String.Format("\\u{0:X4}", (ushort)c);

Answer (score 0):

You could parse the line to get each unicode char. To convert unicode to readable character you could do

```
char MyChar = '\u0058';
```

Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

What if you do something like this:

```
string codePoints = "\u0641 \u064A \u0649 \u0642 \u0625";

UnicodeEncoding uEnc = new UnicodeEncoding();

byte[] bytesToWrite = uEnc.GetBytes(codePoints);
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(@"yadda.txt", bytesToWrite);


byte[] readBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"yadda.txt");
string val = uEnc.GetString(readBytes);
```

//daniel